# How to not repeat wordpress loop/query?

Tags: wordpress

This is a bad habit i've been using in wordpress and i want to stop.  I repeat the loop/query code when i should fetch all at once.  Here is an example...

```
 <?php
                $args = array(
                'p' => 9345, // id of a page, post, or custom type
                'post_type' => 'front page content');

                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                //Display the contents

                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                the_content(); 
     endwhile; 

                $args = array(
                'p' => 9341, // id of a page, post, or custom type
                'post_type' => 'front page content');

                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                //Display the contents

                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

     the_content();  endwhile; 
?>
```

If i want to display the content of the id `9345` first and the content of the id `9341` second, how do i do this all without duplicating WP_Query?  I know about order_by but what if i want to specifically order results from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `post__in`, [Read more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post__in' => array(9345, 9341),
        'post_type' => 'page'
    )

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    //Display the contents

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        the_content(); 
    endwhile; 

    //DONT FORGET THIS
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```